# Does copper exacerbate wounds?

Tags: molecular-biology, toxicology, injury, poison

There is a three edged stiletto (weapon, not shoe) with a triangular cross-section that is often touted as being "extra dangerous" because of the triangular puncture it makes, and its copper construction. The claim is that the copper inclusion causes something colloquially referred to as "blood poisoning."

Is there any basis to the idea that a copper blade would cause some kind of secondary toxic effect?

Comment: Can you post a link either to the weapon itself or to some other source discussing its "extra dangerousness"? I've found some triple-edged stilettos, but nothing made of copper.

Comment: That's the trouble, it's all been anecdotal. I've seen these copper stilettos sold at fairs and whatnot, some of which even by otherwise reputable vendors, but I can't find any info online.

Comment: Copper is a micronutrient and is essential for human body. See [here](http://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/minerals/copper)

Comment: Meaning it is toxic only at levels the body can't handle and its deficiency can cause some health issues

Comment: Ironically, copper and copper-containing alloys are also known to have antimicrobial properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper), meaning that it's conceivable that you'd be *less* likely to get blood poisoning from a copper blade.

Answer (score 2):

Excess copper in the body [can be toxic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_toxicity) but I'm not sure a copper blade would be especially toxic unless it was coated with something else or it remained in the wound. Copper can be acutely toxic when ingested, or chronically over a long period of exposure (like lead), but is more often associated with a failure in copper excretion. Since the body has [ways of dealing with excess copper](http://m.physrev.physiology.org/content/87/3/1011.short), I just don't see much merit in the super-toxic copper blade, unless it is designed to break off in the target.

Comment: I also think, that the copper is much less of a problem than a deep wound by such a weapon.